# Magento 2 : How to Fix Error total_invoiced_amount Value is bad when create a invoice

Tags: magento2.4, create-invoice

In my invoice, I am having problems with a grand total(base) that is always 2 euros for order so the total billed amount of 2 will be subject to tax and shipping. With an error on the at page Dashboard Renevue result negative display. I spent a lot of time trying to find the cause but was still hopeless with this problem. Hope you guys can point me to those who thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: Invoice Grant Total is calculated in \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Total\Grand class, start debugging with this file.

Comment: thank you did reply and I did fix the problem in the file: /var/www/html/designerwholesaleeyewear.com/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php  because our file in function getBaseGrandTotal() missing  return $this->getData(self::KEY_BASE_GRAND_TOTAL); so auto $total = 2.